ElasticSearch - Get uniqe query results by id together with cardinality aggregation
Hello I would like to archive the following, we have a data pool there we store a lot of duplicated items (see a sample below) and i need to query all latest entry's by an distinct id, after wards i need to group the results by state to get a count of the occurences.
I've trying the following query with the result that I'll get items with each state but it should be only the newest item.
e.g with the sample data it should be only 2 and not 3 entries.
{
  "size": 0,
  "sort": [
    { "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "projectName": "XYZ"
          }
        }
      ]
     
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field" : "state", "size": 50
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "item_count": {
         "cardinality": {
            "field": "id"
          }
        }
      }
  }
}


The data structure look like the following:
{
    "state": "Implemented",
    "priority": "Low",
    "severity": "Minor",
    "id": 9898,
    "timestamp": "2024-10-01T00:01:12.881358+00:00",
    "projectName": "XYZ"
},
{
    "state": "Closed",
    "priority": "Low",
    "severity": "Minor",
    "id": 9898,
    "timestamp": "2024-10-08T00:01:12.881358+00:00",
    "projectName": "XYZ"
},
{
    "state": "Implemented",
    "priority": "Low",
    "severity": "Minor",
    "id": 999,
    "timestamp": "2024-10-01T00:01:12.881358+00:00",
    "projectName": "XYZ"
},

Kind regards
